# how would I translate this from searchlogic to metwhere in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, meta-where

I had the following in searchlogic:

```
Todo.contact_id_is(self.id).ascend_by_original_date.done_date_not_null.first
```

How would I do this in metawhere now that I am in Rails 3?  In particular the not_null and the sorting?

Hello, I'm a little confused.  When I look at the named scopes found in meta_search (instead of metawhere)...that's more of what I'm looking for...and now metasearch is being replaced with ransack....

What is the way to do chained searches with sql on my models in the way searchlogic made it so drop-dead easy?

...okay...now it looks like ransack is for forms, but queries on models is squeel?  Checking that out....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that metawhere doesn't have `!=` operator it was added in `sqeel` so here is a  possible workaround

```
Todo.where( { :contact_id => self.id} ).order( :original_date.asc ).where( '"todos"."done_date" NOT NULL' ).first
```

Comment: I see....I don't think contact_id_is works....?  I get a method missing error....

Comment: wait, are you using sqeel instead, should I use sqeel?  How would that help?

Comment: I get an error, does Postgres not handle NULL?  PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NULL"
LINE 1: ... AND "todos"."asset_id" = 1)) AND (todos.done_date NOT NULL)
                                                                  ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "todos" WHERE (("todos"."asset" = 'Email' AND "todos"."asset_id" = 1)) AND (todos.done_date NOT NULL)

Comment: Postgres understands `NULL` but it seems that it uses `"todos"."done_date"` not `todos.done_date`. Try updated version, please. As I understood from documentation `Squeel` is an advanced version of `metawhere`. It has more operators.

Comment: gotcha, thanks....I used what you did with metawhere....I actually found that not_eq is the same as not equal